# Remap right option key in mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, keymapping

Macbook pro 13" does not have a right control key. As a programmer I really need this key and it is not convenient to hit left control with keys that are also on the left side of the keyboard. 
Is there a way to globally change the right option key (which I don't need that much) to the ctrl key in mac?

Comment: See also [emulating-the-right-ctrl-key-on-macbook-pro-keyboard-lacking-an-actual-right-ctr](http://superuser.com/questions/48362/emulating-the-right-ctrl-key-on-macbook-pro-keyboard-lacking-an-actual-right-ctr)

Comment: you can put an answer to your question yourself. putting the answer in the question is not a good idea. If the link provided by @here solves the question, then this is either a duplicate or he/she should give the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found how to remap control keys and I'm including it here for future references: Double command is a software that does exactly the same thing (mapping only the right option key to control key). You can use it to change the control keys of your mac using this application.

```
http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/
```

Comment: This is just a link to a third-party software, it doesn't solve your original question programatically.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Monterey, but Karabiner Elements did

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to use it in the terminal as I did.
I recommend you to use iTerm2. It allows you to remap keys in the `Keys` tab in the `Preferences` pane (shown below):

[image]